# Is $k=3$ the only solution to $\sum_{r=1}^n r^k =\left( \sum_{r=1}^nr^1 \right)^2 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$f(k) = \sum_{r=1}^{n} r^k$. Find an integer $x$ that solves the equation $f(x) = \bigl(f(1)\bigr)^2$.

Problem credit: http://cotpi.com/p/2/

I understand why $x = 3$ is a solution. $1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}\right)^2 = (1 + 2 + \dots + n)^2$. But how can we prove that there is no other solution?

Will we have other solutions if $x$ is real? What if $x$ is complex?

Comment: (Note: the title had its variables wrong in the sum limit and the expressions.  I've fixed it to match the question.)

Answer (score 4):

At least for real x, f(x) for a given n increases with x. So there can be only one solution at most. Since 3 is a solution, there is no other.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the question is really asking you to compare two *functions* of n: 'solves the equation' is slightly poor wording here, since you're being asked to show that two functions are equal and not two values.  To show that they're *inequal* as functions of $n$, for all other values of $k$, it suffices to just find a single value of $n$ where they differ, so consider $n=2$; then $f(1)^2 = (1^1+2^1)^2 = 9$, whereas $f(k) = 1+2^k$.  This should make it clear why there's only one possible value of $k$ that can lead to a match - there's only one value of $k$ that even matches at this particular $n$.  The trick is then showing the match for $k=3$ and all other $n$, which you've already established.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, one can look for expressions of the form 
$f(k) = \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor} a_j f(j) f(n+1-j)$.  It seems to work for all odd $k$.  For example:

$$\eqalign{f \left( 3 \right) &= \left( f \left( 1 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cr
f \left( 5 \right) &=4\,f \left( 1 \right) f \left( 3 \right) -3\,
 \left( f \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cr
f \left( 7 \right) &=6\,f \left( 1 \right) f \left( 5 \right) -15\,f
 \left( 2 \right) f \left( 4 \right) +10\, \left( f \left( 3 \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\cr
f \left( 9 \right) &=8\,f \left( 1 \right) f \left( 7 \right) -28\,f
 \left( 2 \right) f \left( 6 \right) +56\,f \left( 3 \right) f \left( 
5 \right) -35\, \left( f \left( 4 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cr
f \left( 11 \right) &=10\,f \left( 1 \right) f \left( 9 \right) -45\,f
 \left( 2 \right) f \left( 8 \right) +120\,f \left( 3 \right) f
 \left( 7 \right) -210\,f \left( 4 \right) f \left( 6 \right) +126\,
 \left( f \left( 5 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cr
}$$

Hmm, looks like $$f(2k+1) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2k-1} (-1)^{j+1} {2k \choose j} f(j) f(2k-j) $$

Ought to be easy to prove...

EDIT: yes, it is.  By the binomial theorem

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{2k-1} \sum_{q=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{j+1} {2k \choose j} q^j r^{2k-j}
= \sum_{q=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^n \left(r^{2k} + q^{2k} - (r-q)^{2k}\right)$$
and note that $$\sum_{q=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^n (r-q)^{2k} = \sum_{s=1}^n 2 (n-s) s^{2k} =
2 n f(2k) - 2 f(2k+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $p(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to find values of $x$ for which $f(x) = (f(1))^2$ as functions in $n$. In this case, we can simply substitute in $n=1$, $n=2$, and $n=3$. Namely, we need to satisfy $$1^x=1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 1^x + 2^x = 9 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 1^x + 2^x + 3^x = 36$$ Subtracting successive equations yields $$2^x = 8 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 3^x = 27$$ Obviously, $x = 3$ is the only real value which works. You might wonder whether there are any complex values. Suppose $x=a+bi$. Then $$8=2^x = 2^a2^{bi} = 2^ae^{ib\ln{2}}$$ Matching magnitudes, we need $2^a=3$, so that $a = 3$. Meanwhile, notice that $b$ must take the form $\frac{2\pi}{\ln{2}}m$ for some integer $m$. If we continue this analysis for the equation $3^x=27$, we also need that $b = \frac{2\pi}{\ln{3}}n$ for some integer $n$. Setting these expressions for $b$ equal and solving yields $$m \ln{3} = n\ln{2},$$ or equivalently, $$3^m = 2^n,$$ which is only true when $m=n=0$. Therefore, $b=0$, and so $x=3$ is the only value for which $f(x) = (f(1))^2$ for every $n$.