# Are there $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ that ${(\sum_{k=1}^n k)}^a = \sum_{k=1}^n k^b $ beside $2,3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

We know that:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 $$

My question is there other examples that satisfies: 
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^a = \sum_{k=1}^n k^b $$

Comment: You might find this useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149223/is-k-3-the-only-solution-to-sum-r-1n-rk-left-sum-r-1nr1-right?rq=1

Comment: Well, there is $a=b=1$.

Comment: One wants that $$\left(\frac{n^2}2\right)^a\sim\frac{n^{b+1}}{b+1}$$ when $n\to\infty$ hence $$2a=b+1=2^a,$$ and one can conclude.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials

Comment: Essentially, you want new non-trivial solutions to $3^a = 1+2^b$, which is impossible, thanks to the [Catalan's_conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1292636/11619).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can write

$$\sum^n_{k=1} k^a = \frac{1}{a+1} n^{a+1} + O(n^a).$$

The easiest way to convince yourself of this is to use a comparison test with an integral.

Thus, for the following to hold
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^a = \sum_{k=1}^n k^b,$$
we need the highest order terms in the polynomials to be equal:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^a n^{2a} = \frac{1}{b+1} n^{b+1}.$$

This gives the simultaneous set of equations

$$2^a=b+1$$
and
$$2a=b+1.$$

This can only hold when $a=2$, and hence $b=4-1=3$, or $a=1$ and $b=2-1=1$.

Certainly, we have $f(a)=2^a-2a$ for integer $a$ so $f''(a)=(\ln a)^2 2^a > 0$ and $f$ is strictly convex. It is easily shown that such a function cannot have more than two zeros immediately from the definition of convexity. Hence our two solutions are unique.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=1+2+3+\cdots+n = \dfrac{n(n+1)} 2$.

Then whenever $p$ is an **odd** number, the sum
$$
1^p+2^p+3^p+\cdots + n^p
$$
can be written as a polynomial function of $a$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials

Answer (score 0):

Put $n=2.$ Then the RHS is$$S=\sum k^b=2^b+1=\frac{2^{2b}-1}{2^b-1}.$$ By [Zsigmondy's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZsigmondyTheorem.html), if $b\ne 3$, there is a prime $p$ where the order of 2 mod $p$ is $2b$, and so $p\mid S$. (If $b=3$, the RHS is $9=3^2$ and there is no such $p$, for the order of 2 mod 3 is 2, not 6.)

Further, $p\mid (2^c+1)$ only if $b\mid c$, thus not for any $0<c<b$. But the only primes that divide $\left[\sum k\right]^a$ are those that divide $3^a$, viz 3.

Even if the LHS were generalised to $S=\left[\sum k^c\right]^a$, then, for a non-trivial solution, $a>1$ and $c<b$, so the above prime $p\nmid S$.